# How to compile GTK3 Libray and up with Cmake instead of meson

Tags: c, cmake, compilation, gtk, meson-build

I like to compile the GTK3 Library with cmake instead of meson as mason

Meson needs Python11.dll(windows 10 or higher) and MSYS2 requires Windows 8 or higher eventually i like to switch to Linux fully so im trying to avoid WinspyOS/Updateshell

Comment: Did you read the GTK3 doc on [how to compile a GTK application](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/compiling.html) ? Or are you trying to build GTK?

Comment: That is to compile a program using the GTK Library  i like to compile the Library on windows? i dont have acces to linux at all times(work)

Comment: Switching build systems is a lot of work.  Have you considered alternatives such as using docker or WSL?

Answer (score 1):

You can't build a project using build system A when it uses build system B internally. Specifically for this case: CMake doesn't magically know what to do with `meson.build` files and vice versa. So the answer to your original question is: no, you can't do this.

The GTK docs provides [a section in its documentation](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows) on how to build for Windows using either MSYS2 or gvsbuild. If neither of those work out for you, you'll have to resort to using containerization technologies like docker/podman, WSL, or a virtual machine.

Comment: Not helpful i'm trying to find a way to convert it from meson to Cmake

Comment: The only way to convert it to CMake is to write all the necessary `CMakeLists.txt` files for GTK yourself. That'll be an insane amount of work, and you'll _still_ need to understand/build with meson to make sure you're not accidentally using different compiler/linker flags.